# SwiftUI Navigation title overlapping

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation

[image]

Headings overlap after navigating to and from SwiftUI navigation screen. Here is My Code.

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        ForEach(productCategories) { index in
            NavigationLink(destination: AllProductsList(categoryID: index.categoryID, categoryTitle: index.name)) {
                ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                    VStack {
                        WebImage(url: URL(string: serviceLink + "/image/" + index.image))
                            .resizable()
                            .indicator(.activity)
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(width: screen.width - 30, height: 300, alignment: .center)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous))
                    }
                    Text(index.name)
                        .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()

                }
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle(Text("Kategoriler"))
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
```

Comment: The above code works fine for me though. Maybe show your code from the destination view as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve the problem

```
.isDetaillink(false)
```

I need to add it to the end of Navigation Link

Comment: Only works if you have NavigationLinks in the list rows.  In my case, I don't, I have detail icons similar to how Reminders app does it, so can't find an alterantive fix.  The problem only manifests in design mode, if you go into 'Live Preview' mode, the overlap disappears.